# Promoting widget to use custom widget class is not working due to bad header file path

Tags: qgis, python

I am trying to implement a custom QtableWidget using QGIS plugin builder and the QT Designer. I have created a TestTableWidget class and promoted an empty table widget to use this class. I have been having trouble with the header file location.

It seems to think it is in the `'C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\clusterpoints'` directory sometimes. That plugin must mess with the global python path that plugin builder sets?

I disabled that plugin and restarted QGIS. Now it does not know where to find the module. How do I use a custom class that has been promoted using Qt Designer in a QGIS plugin?

The plugin folder structure is like:

```
estimator    
    __init__.py
    estimator_dialog_base.ui
    estimator_dialog.py
    estimator.py
    testtablewidget.py
    resources.py
    resources.qrc
```

**estimator_dialog_base.ui** has the following lines of code where it defines the custom widget. I unchecked the global include option in the gui designer promotion menu. there is no actual file **testtablewidget.h** located anywhere. **testtablewidget.py** exists and I think uic [does some black magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19622817/17639508) where it turns into a working import.

```
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>TestTableWidget</class>
   <extends>QTableWidget</extends>
   <header>testtablewidget.h</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
```

**estimator_dialog.py**

```
import os

from qgis.PyQt import uic
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets

# This loads your .ui file so that PyQt can populate your plugin with the elements from Qt Designer
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'estimator_dialog_base.ui'))


class EstimatorDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(EstimatorDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer through FORM_CLASS.
        # After self.setupUi() you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)
```

**estimator.py**

```
class Estimator:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'Estimator_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&The Estimator')

        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = None

        # geometry is None
        self.geometry = None

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Estimator', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/estimator/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'The Estimator'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&The Estimator'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)

        ....
```

**testtablewidget.py**

```
class FloatDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        editor.setValidator(QDoubleValidator())
        return editor


class TestTableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        path = pathlib.Path(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        self.path = pathlib.Path(path / 'Price_Lists' / 'materials.csv')
        self.df = pandas.read_csv(self.path, index_col = 'Item')
        nRows = len(self.df.index)
        nColumns = len(self.df.columns)
        self.setRowCount(nRows)
        self.setColumnCount(nColumns)
        self.setItemDelegate(FloatDelegate())

        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                x = '{:.3f}'.format(self.df.iloc[i, j])
                self.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(x))

        self.cellChanged.connect(self.onCellChanged)

    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def onCellChanged(self, row, column):
        text = self.item(row, column).text()
        number = float(text)
        self.df.set_value(row, column, number)
```

[image]

**Errors:**

```
Couldn't load plugin 'estimator' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testtablewidget' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 334, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\estimator\__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
    from .estimator import Estimator
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\estimator\estimator.py", line 35, in 
    from .estimator_dialog import EstimatorDialog
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\estimator\estimator_dialog.py", line 32, in 
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'estimator_dialog_base.ui'))
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\PyQt\uic\__init__.py", line 36, in __loadUiType
    return __PyQtLoadUiType(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 201, in loadUiType
    exec(code_string.getvalue(), ui_globals)
  File "", line 16250, in 
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testtablewidget'


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.16.3-Hannover Hannover, 94ac9f21b8 

Python Path:
C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\clusterpoints 
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\Scripts
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python37.zip
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

Comment: Had the same issue. This answer works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72433557/19954013